# Send large amount of chars to PHP from javascript using Ajax using POST method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my JS file

```
function save()
{

    var hist = document.getElementById("hist").value;
                var mission =   document.getElementById("mission").value;

            var params = "history=" + hist+ "&mission=" + mission;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) 
            {

                 UserAccountInfo =   this.responseText;
                 alert(UserAccountInfo);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","savecompany.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(params);  
}
```

hist msg will be

> Founded by Engineer Anas El-Menoufi after 8 years of experience as
>   marketing advisor and business development manager for W.C Heraus GmbH
>   in Africa and Middle East. Since 1983 MYMSA is recognized in the
>   Egyptian market as one of the first companies in Egypt and MENA region
>   specialized in the supply of solutions, instrumentation, consultancy
>   and after sales service for primary & secondary testing and
>   calibration laboratories in many fields.

and mission will be

> Aims to gain customers' trust & satisfaction by providing the best
>   consultancy, raising the market awareness as well as partnering with
>   the best manufacturers all over the world.
>
> We believe that building our internal capabilities will reflect on the
>   market.

after sending these variables to PHP file

hist became

> Founded by Engineer Anas El-Menoufi after 8 years of experience as
>   marketing advisor and business development manager for W.C Heraus GmbH
>   in Africa and Middle East. Since 1983 MYMSA is recognized in the
>   Egyptian market as one of the first companies in Egypt and MENA region
>   specialized in the supply of solutions, instrumentation, consultancy
>   and after sales service for primary

and mission

> Aims to gain customers' trust

Only!!! 
Why this happens??? And how can I send the whole large message ??

This is my PHP file

```
<?php

    require "conn.php";


    $history= $_POST["history"];
    $mission = $_POST["mission"];

    $sql = " UPDATE company SET history ='$history' , mission='$mission'  where id='1'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


echo "done";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: @AustenHolland I don't think so. This is another problem

Comment: Well, it's a related problem. You need to sanitize inputs. Your problem is happening because you haven't sanitized the JavaScript input, but you've also got a giant SQL hole that'll continue to cause you issues. Time to learn about SQL injection vulnerabilities and parameterized MySQL queries - a `'` in `$history` will break your site.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you *should* be posting this kind of data within the body/payload of the POST request, but here's why your current solution isn't working:

As you can see, your text stops just before the "&" symbol in the text - this is because the & symbol is a URL component to append another query parameter - this needs to be encoded into %26, and luckily JavaScript has a function to do this, `encodeURIComponent`.

When creating your params variable, you can use `encodeURIComponent` like this:

```
var params = "history=" + encodeURIComponent(hist) + "&mission=" + encodeURIComponent(mission);
```

Comment: No, It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data into something that Javascript on php understand i.e.

```
var params = ["history" : hist,
              "mission" : mission];
params = JSON.stringify( params );
```

Then on the php side use:

```
$history = $_POST['history'];
$mission = $_POST['mission';
```